# Configure ng-show and ng-hide speed

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, angularjs-ng-show

Please can I modify the speed of Angular's ng-show and ng-hide? jQuery has parameters to modify the speed of show() and hide(), so I'm just wondering if that can be done with Angular.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure can, Have a look at the [ng-animate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) stuff that Angular provides. [Here's an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/BwTXGqtPaIPacN8grbRj?p=info) from their docs that you can tweak. The speed is defined in the CSS file:

```
transition: all linear 0.5s;
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, another way to do what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could bind them to model properties which change on a timer.

So have a property in your controller which show/hide is bound to:

```
$scope.myObject = {
    showElement: false;
};
```

Then in your view:

```
<div ng-show="myObject.showElement">Boom!</div>
```

And then your timer (using Angular):

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.myObject.showElement = true;
}, 100);
```

Comment: This just adds a delay until the object is shown, I think OP wants the show/hide to ease in/out.

Comment: @BenHeymink Ah, then your answer is the way to go.